# How to make a semantic dropdown menu occupy space

Tags: semantic-ui

I need a semantic-ui dropdown to push content down, i.e. not overlap what comes after. The classic way to do this is to set position; relative, as in

```
.ui.dropdown .menu {
    position: relative !important; 
}
```

The result is that the menu border has unwanted margins, the right margin is large because the `ui.dropdown.icon` occupies space. Any idea how to make this work? 
As a workaround, I tried intercepting add,remove,show,hide and calculate a spacer outside of the dropdown but that code has to wait until the transition is done to calculate the spacer height.

Comment: My best attempt to make it work: `.ui.dropdown .menu {
 position: relative !important; 
 margin-left: -6px !important;
 margin-bottom: -8px !important;
 width: calc(100% + 2.6em) !important;
}`